# Is 'unpersist' lazy evaluated in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In spark, `cache` is lazy evaluated until an action is called. Does the same lazy evaluation applies to `unpersist`as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unpersist()` immediately removes persisted objects from memory

You can confirm this in the Spark UI under `storage` tab.
The cached `df` partitions will be removed after `df.unpersist()` command is executed.

```py
df = spark.range(10) # sample df
df.cache() # lazy narrow transformation
df.foreach(lambda x: x) # materialize cache via action
df.unpersist() # remove persisted dataframe from cached RAM
```